# App freeze when tap on textfield in conditional section

Tags: forms, swiftui, sections

I have a textfield that can be modified programatically.
It works fine, until the form section is conditionally displayed, in that case the app freezes when I use the textfield.

Here is my code (I removed unnecessary stuff):

```
struct test: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var displaySection = true
    @State private var amount: Double?
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {
                if displaySection {     // <-- works well without that condition, otherwise app freezes
                    Section {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Amount EUR")
                                Spacer()
                                TextField("Type amount", value: $amount, format: .number)
                                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                    .focused($isFocused)
                            }
                            Text("Set MAX (999)")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    isFocused = false
                                    amount = 999
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to have some sections hidden in the form so I'm stuck on that, didn't succeed to skirt this issue. Problem appears on simulator as well on device.

Is this behavior normal, or is there a possible workaround ?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: try putting in an `else` it could be because there is no fallback

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately same behaviour...

Comment: I run your code with Xcode **13.2.1** on a simulator with iOS **15.2** and a device with iOS **15.3.1**. If you're able to reproduce it on these versions, make sure your example is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. try running it in a new project.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, I run also on same versions. I don't get your point, do you reproduce or not ? Beside that, I think my example conforms to minimal reproducible example, I removed all unecessary parts to get to the point.

Comment: Try running your application without debug mode: install it, close the application and reopen it manually to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with Xcode 13.2.1 on Intel and iOS 15.2 I can only get this example code to lock-up in the simulator and on a real device if I type a number of more than three digits in the 'Amount EUR' and then attempt to 'Set the Max to 999' i.e. a three digit number.

In previous versions of SwiftUI the only input binding TextField would work with was String. It seems likely that although the current version accepts binding to numerics the way it is doing this is to map, and the underlying mechanism remains that of the original String based TextField (typing in the TextField with an attached keyboard still unfortunately renders non-numeric characters regardless of keyboardType as it did the last time I experimented  https://gist.github.com/shufflingB/23daafa5253c3355cdf18934599cd54c)

For whatever reason this new(ish) mapping process appears to be getting confused when more than three digits are entered and the TextField is then by default automatically adding a number grouping character.

Two work-arounds seem to address the problem:

1. Push the change to `amount` triggered by `Set the Max ...` to a later state update cycle using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`
2. Give an option to remove the troublesome grouping character from the TextField.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var displaySection = true
    @State private var amount: Double?
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                if displaySection {
                    Section {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Amount EUR")
                                Spacer()
                                TextField("Type amount", value: $amount, format: .number)
                                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                    .focused($isFocused)

                                /* Alternative to Dispatch, remove number grouping
                                TextField("Type amount", value: $amount, format: .number.grouping(.never))
                                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                    .focused($isFocused)
                                 */
                            }
                            Text("Set MAX (999)")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    isFocused = false
                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { // <- Push change to subsequent update cycle
                                        amount = 999
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These two solutions work like a charm. I understood the behavior of the textField, but I don't see the relation with the fact that the section is conditioned or not. Anyway thanks for these explanations and workarounds, helps me a lot !

Comment: Few more thoughts on it ... 1 of 2 -  Unsure if it is generally true across SwiftUI. But TextField's @Binding is implemented by synchronising changes backwards and forwards between its parent and one or more internal copies (one of which is the String representation which allows the numeric TextField to have non-numeric entry via attached keyboards and cut and paste). That two-way sync across the copies is not instantaneous. So for each copy, there has to be a mechanism to reconcile what to set from possibly multiple values presented and avoid infinite feedback loops.

Comment: 2 of 2 - At a guess, it is this TextField reconciliation and anti-feedback mechanism that is borderline functional. With it, outside of simple circumstances failing to complete in time (depending on hardware) and entering into an infinite feedback loop. I think what happened is the conditional just pushed it over the edge on your hardware; for me, it took the addition of grouping character. Worth reporting to Apple, original code should have been fine. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer.

You presented a really weird behaviour in your app, I would never imagine such bug. I tested your code, it actually freezes the app.

Now, I tested the solution below: move your `Section` to a separate view. In my Xcode, it works.

```
struct Example: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var displaySection = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {
                if displaySection {     // <-- works well ALSO WITH that condition
                    ConditionalSection()
                }
                
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        displaySection.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Display or not display?")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ConditionalSection: View {
    @State private var amount: Double?
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Amount EUR")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Type amount", value: $amount, format: .number)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .focused($isFocused)
                }
                Text("Set MAX (999)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isFocused = false
                        amount = 999
                    }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This workaround works, based on the example. IRL, the amount needs to be known in the example view, not only in ConditionalSection view. So I defined amount in the example view and add @binding on ConditionalView. And as soon as I use the amount value on example view, in Text or whatever, the app freezes again. Seems it's a Swiftui bug, but difficult to cope with :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. An idea: did you try to store the amount in the view model? In this way, you will have two views reading from the same view model and avoid the binding. I didn't test it yet, can't tell you if it will work.